# Strange problems with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, emulation

I'm having some strange problems with a webpage that everyone else swears is working just fine.  One developer told me it could be because my IE11 browser is emulating IE8.  Never heard of such a thing. How do I find out, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Press F12 to open the developer tools. Look at the compatibility bar at the top. Fix it by validating and fixing your HTML.

Comment: Emulation is good, VM is better with [IE 8](https://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer)